# Using the LIKE operator with a wildcard using API v3's REST interface

Tags: api, rest

I am trying to do a simple `GET` request using a `LIKE` operator with a wildcard. It's easy to set up the explorer and works as expected. I'm using a demo civi environment using the example data included on install. There are two Heidis in the database.

The rest URL generated in the explorer is:
`https://civi.site.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php ?entity=Contact &action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"first_name":{"LIKE":"Heid%"}}`

As is, I know that the URL will generate the error: `Unable to decode supplied JSON.`

I have reformatted it to:
`https://civi.site.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?key=sitekey&api_key=userkey&entity=Contact&sequential=1&json=1&action=get&first_name=Heidi`

That works as expected using the exact match on `Heidi`. I tried using the `LIKE` operator using array syntax:
`https://civi.site.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?key=sitekey&api_key=userkey&entity=Contact&sequential=1&json=1&action=get&first_name[like]=Heidi`

I get the expected response, but this uses the exact value and no wildcard characters.

I've tried three different options for wildcards:

1. Like array no wildcard:
   `https://civi.site.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?key=sitekey&api_key=userkey&entity=Contact&sequential=1&json=1&action=get&first_name[like]=Heid`
2. Like array with wildcard:
   `https://civi.site.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?key=sitekey&api_key=userkey&entity=Contact&sequential=1&json=1&action=get&first_name[like]=Heid%`
3. Like array with encoded wildcard:
   `https://civi.site.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?key=sitekey&api_key=userkey&entity=Contact&sequential=1&json=1&action=get&first_name[like]=Heid%25`

None of the three wildcard attempts produce an error, but they return 0 results. I've looked through the docs and have done multiple Google searches but I can't find a workable solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct syntax is the one at the top:

"first_name": {"LIKE":"hei%"}

to work around the encoding issues (that might be tricky indeed), don't try to put all the params in the url (as http get) but use a http post (the api works with both)

Comment: Each of the top three works, it's really just the wildcard character that I'm struggling with.

Comment: use http post instead of get, solves the dealing with escaping of % and json

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to do it as a multipart/form-data POST.